# Simplify jquery function for automatic button

Tags: jquery, button

I've done something that seems to be very long for something maybe simple... So do you have a simplier way to do this ?

I got this page :

```
<div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><h2>Titre 1</h2></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Choix</td>
                <td><form:checkbox path="cas5"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Libell&eacute;</td>
                <td colspan="3"><form:input path="libelleCas5" class="libelle" size="100" maxlength="100" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Statut</td> 
                <td><form:input path="statutCas5" class="statut" size="10" maxlength="2" /></td>
                <td align="right">Dossier</td>  
                <td><form:input path="numDossierCas5" size="10" maxlength="2" /></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td align="left">D&eacute;tail</td> 
                <td colspan="3"><form:input path="detailSuiviCas5" class="detail" size="100" maxlength="500" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Contact</td>   
                <td colspan="3"><form:input path="contactCas5" class="contact" size="50" maxlength="50" /></td>
            </tr>
         </table>   
     </div>
     <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><h2>Titre 2</h2></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Choix</td>
                <td><form:checkbox path="cas6"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Libell&eacute;</td>
                <td colspan="3"><form:input path="libelleCas6" class="libelle" size="100" maxlength="100" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Statut</td> 
                <td><form:input path="statutCas6" class="statut" size="10" maxlength="2" /></td>
                <td align="right">Dossier</td>  
                <td><form:input path="numDossierCas6" size="10" maxlength="2" /></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td align="left">D&eacute;tail</td> 
                <td colspan="3"><form:input path="detailSuiviCas6" class="detail" size="100" maxlength="500" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Contact</td>   
                <td colspan="3" ><form:input path="contactCas6" class="contact" size="50" maxlength="50" /></td>
            </tr>
         </table>   
     </div>
```

I want to add a button with a "mailto" link after each contact zone (each input with class=contact).

I did that with jQuery like this :

```
$(".contact").each(function () {
    var libelleTmp = $(this).parents('table').find('.libelle').val().replace(/'/g, " ").replace(/"/g, " ");
    var detailTmp = $(this).parents('table').find('.detail').val().replace(/'/g, " ").replace(/"/g, " ");
    var onclickvalue = "mailto:" + $(this).val() + "?subject=" + libelleTmp + "&body=" + detailTmp + "\';";
    console.log($(this).val() + libelleTmp);
    var bouton = '<tr class="boutonMail"><td colspan=4><input type="button" onclick="window.location=\'' + onclickvalue + '" value="Envoyer email" /></tr></td>';
    console.log(bouton);
    $(this).parents('table').append(bouton);
    if ($(this).parents('table').find('.statut').val() == 'BL' && !$(this).val()) {
        $(this).parents('table').find('.boutonMail').hide();
    }
}).change(function () {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    var emailaddressVal = $(this).val();
    if (emailaddressVal == '') {} else if (!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {
        $(this).parents('table').find('.boutonMail').hide();
    } else {
        var libelleTmp = $(this).parents('table').find('.libelle').val().replace(/'/g, " ").replace(/"/g, " ");
        var detailTmp = $(this).parents('table').find('.detail').val().replace(/'/g, " ").replace(/"/g, " ");
        var onclickvalue = "mailto:" + $(this).val() + "?subject=" + libelleTmp + "&body=" + detailTmp + "\';";
        console.log($(this).val() + libelleTmp);
        var bouton = '<tr class="boutonMail"><td colspan=4><input type="button" onclick="window.location=\'' + onclickvalue + '" value="Envoyer email" /></tr></td>';
        console.log(bouton);
        $(this).parents('table').find('.boutonMail').replaceWith(bouton);

        $(this).parents('table').find('.boutonMail').show();
    }
});
```

It's a little bit long... Do you have a simpler way to do this ?

Many thanks

Comment: StackExchange has a new site called 'code review' http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  You should post this there or see if someone can move it. So it would be: StackOverflow (problems/clarification) CR (improvements/refining).

Comment: well at the very least - if (emailaddressVal == '') {} else if (!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal)) - can be simplified

Comment: What template engine are you using ?

Comment: just jQuery-1.11.0.min

Comment: I mean to generate your html : `<form:input />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I would try to make an object in order to prevent code duplication :

**[The Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9HtFM/)**

```
function mailToButton(contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
    this.tableParent = this.contact.parents('table');
    this.libelleTmp = this.tableParent.find('.libelle').val().replace(/'/g, " ").replace(/"/g, " ");
    this.detailTmp = this.tableParent.find('.detail').val().replace(/'/g, " ").replace(/"/g, " ");
    this.emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    this.appendToTable = function() {
        this.tableParent.append(this.getHtml());
        if (this.tableParent.find('.statut').val() == 'BL' && !this.contact.val()) {
            this.tableParent.find('.boutonMail').hide();
        }
    };
    this.getOnclickValue = function() {
        return "mailto:" + contact.val() + "?subject=" + this.libelleTmp + "&body=" + this.detailTmp + "\';";
    };
    this.getHtml = function() {
        return '<tr class="boutonMail"><td colspan=4><input type="button" onclick="window.location=\'' + 
            this.getOnclickValue() + 
            '" value="Envoyer email" /></tr></td>';
    };
    this.mailIsValid = function() {
        return this.emailReg.test(this.contact.val());
    };
    this.refresh = function() {
        var buttonMail = this.tableParent.find('.boutonMail');
        if(!this.mailIsValid()) {
            buttonMail.hide();
        } else if (this.contact.val() != '') {
            buttonMail.replaceWith(this.getHtml());
            buttonMail.show();
        }
    };
}
```

And then just a little piece of code on document ready :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contact").each(function () {
        var button = new mailToButton($(this));
        button.appendToTable();
        $(this).data('button', button);
    }).change(function () {
        var button = $(this).data('button');
        button.refresh();
    });
});
```

This also make the code far more readable and modular.